# Error: "Activation could not be completed because the InfoPath Forms Services support feature is not present ."

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, forms-services

We have been using form uploaded on sharepoint online and after a simple modification (adding some text fields) the form shows the following error:

**"Activation could not be completed because the InfoPath Forms Services support feature is not present ."**
I have tried with no success:

- a) Uploading an old versión that used to work;
- b) Creating a new form library for the same form;
- c) Creating a new form library for a new form;

All other site collections in the farm do not have this issue. Please help on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try de-activating and reactivating the "SharePoint Server Enterprise" features at both the site collection and the site level.

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

Try de-activating and re-activating "**IPFSSiteFeatures**" feature. It is a hidden site collection feature. We can do that with PowerShell.

The "IPFSSiteFeatures" feature id "`c88c4ff1-dbf5-4649-ad9f-c6c426ebcbf5`".

[SharePoint Online: Deactivate Feature using PowerShell](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/06/sharepoint-online-deactivate-feature-using-powershell.html)

[How to enable a SharePoint Online Feature using PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/How-to-enable-a-SharePoint-5bb614c7)

Comment: did this, it did not work

Comment: Check my update

Comment: thanks, would do it, but just curious, would it impact any existing functionality? Should I take backup of my form templates?

Comment: IPFSSiteFeatures: Name: InfoPath Forms Services support 
Description: InfoPath Forms Services lists and related pages to enable server side rendering of Forms. You can backup the site before any changes.

Comment: The re-activation of "IPFSSiteFeatures" did the trick. Thanks for thi solution @JoannaW_MSFT

Answer (score 0):

```
Disable-SPFeature "IPFSSiteFeatures" -URL "http://yoursitecollectionURL" 
Enable-SPFeature "IPFSSiteFeatures" -URL "http://yoursitecollectionURL"
```

This fix worked for me.